# How do I use a check box in a calculation?

Tags: c#, methods, checkbox

I'm trying to do the following with two check boxes. One being Medical/Dental deductions and the other a 401k deduction.

I can provide my code for the rest of my project if you'd like. I am trying to get the desired output described below. I receive this output instead of the desired one:

**Name: Joe
Hours: 45
Rate: 10.00
Gross Pay: $400.00
Taxes: $112.50
Net Pay: $337.50
Medical/Dental deduction: $400.00
401k deduction: $20.00**

**·         Handle two possible pretax deductions if applicable (use two check boxes):
·         Medical/dental deduction - $50.00 is deducted from gross pay if this option is  selected

·         401k deduction – 5% is deducted from gross pay if this option is selected
·         Tax is calculated after all deductions (25% of amount after applicable deductions)
·         Include deduction amounts in the rich text box and label each amount properly**

I also have to do a test case to see if it works:

**·         Input: hours = 45, rate 10.00, both Medical/Dental and 401k check boxes are checked
·         Output: gross pay = 475.00, medical/dental deduction 50.00, 401k deduction = 23.75, tax = 100.31, net pay = 300.94**

I have tried to get this started, but don't know where to start. I gave it a shot and here is what I have. It's not within the check box methods, but in the calculate button method where the rest of the calculations are:

```
//Medical/Dental and 401k deductions...as well as tax collected.

  if (MedicalDentalDeductions.Checked)
      {
            Gross_pay = Convert.ToInt32(HoursTextBox.Text) * decimal.Parse(RateTextBox.Text) - 50.00m;
        }


        if (FourOneKDeduction.Checked)
        {
            Gross_pay = Convert.ToInt32(HoursTextBox.Text) * decimal.Parse(RateTextBox.Text) - 0.05m * 100;

        }

     if ((MedicalDentalDeductions.Checked) && (FourOneKDeduction.Checked))
    { Taxes = TAX * Gross_pay; }
      DisplayOutPut.Text= "Medical/Dental deduction:" + Taxes +"401k deduction:"+ Taxes;

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you *have* gotten started which is great, could you please go into more detail about the problems you're currently encountering with your implementation?

Comment: "I gave it a shot and here is what I have." - Describe what is wrong with what you have.  Are you getting an error message, or just the wrong result?

Comment: Can't stop laughing about @tnw 's comment. If you break down your business logic into mathematical equations it would be easy to understand. Just say `'Both checked:'` and `'One checked:'` etc ..

Comment: I checked both check boxes for my test case and got the following result in the rich text box I have in my form:

Medical/Dental deduction:111.2500401k deduction:111.2500

Comment: You should translate your test cases into unit tests and start from there.

Comment: Name: Joe
Hours: 45
Rate: 10.00
Gross Pay: $400.00
Taxes: $112.50
Net Pay: $337.50
Medical/Dental deduction: $400.00
401k deduction: $20.00

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like this:

```
//Medical/Dental and 401k deductions...as well as tax collected.
decimal Gross_pay= Convert.ToInt32(HoursTextBox.Text) * decimal.Parse(RateTextBox.Text);
decimal deductionMed = 0.00m;
decimal deduction401k = 0.00m
  if (MedicalDentalDeductions.Checked)
      {
             deductionMed =  - 50.00m;
        }


        if (FourOneKDeduction.Checked)
        {
            deduction401k = Gross_pay * 0.05m;

        }

      Taxes = TAX * (Gross_pay -(deductionMed + deduction401k)); 
      DisplayOutPut.Text= "Medical/Dental deduction:" + deductionMed +"  401k deduction:"+ deduction401k + "Taxes:"+Taxes ;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking it down into step-by-step calculation like you would do it in excel or manually -

```
int hours = 45;
double payRate = 10.00;
double taxRate = 0.25;

double gross = hours * payRate;

double medical = (MedicalDentalDeductions.Checked) ? 50 : 0;
double retirement = (ForOneKDeduction.Checked) ? gross * 0.05 : 0;

double pretax = gross - medical - retirement;
double tax = pretax * taxRate;

double net = gross - tax;
```

Comment: Good answer. But I think conditional operators might be a little advance for OP